# The application can not locate Python39.dll (126) The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pywinauto

I have tried to make a exe from my python project with pysintaller, but I encounter
error:
The application can not locate Python39.dll (126) The specified module could not be found.

At first I tried using **Python 3.9** that I had installed, then I tried installing **version 2.5** and I still get the same error message.

This issue was mentioned on Pywinauto's Github in december 2020 without a proper solution or a working workaround. It seems that Pywin32 library used in Pywinauto is incompatible with pyinstaller..

Is there an alternate way to produce an exe without pyinstaller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate way to produce an exe is [Nuitka](https://nuitka.net/).
For exemple, Pywinauto recorder is compiled with Nuitka.
You will find all the files to compile Pywinauto recorder in https://github.com/beuaaa/pywinauto_recorder/tree/master/bin

Here is the command line that allows you to compile a Python module:

```
python.exe -m nuitka --standalone --mingw64 your_main.py
```